# What is wrong with my code to calculate quadratic equations in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, quadratic

```
def quad(a, b, c):
    solution1 = (-b + ((b**2 - 4 * a * c)**0.5)) / 2 * a
    solution2 = (-b - ((b**2 - 4 * a * c)**0.5)) / 2 * a
    return solution1, solution2

while True:
    print "\nax^2 + bx + c = 0"
    a = input("What does 'a' equal? ")
    b = input("What does 'b' equal? ")
    c = input("What does 'c' equal? ")

    answera, answerb = quad(a, b, c)
    print "(x -", str(answera) + ")(x -", str(answerb) + ") = 0"
    print "x=" + str(answera) + ",x=" + str(answerb)
```

The code works for any numbers on 'b' and 'c', (within reason), but whenever 'a' is anything but 1, the code gives the wrong numbers, and I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Can you provide sample input (working and failing), current result, desired result and an explanation of the failure?

Answer (score 7):

When you write `/ 2 * a` you first divide by 2, then multiply by `a`.

You want to write `/ (2 * a)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works!

Answer (score 3):

In the order of operations, in your statement

```
solution1 = (-b + ((b**2 - 4 * a * c)**0.5)) / 2 * a
```

, the division by 2 is done first, then the multiplication of that result by `a`. That is not what you want: you want the result of `2*a` divided into the rest. Solve this by putting parentheses around the denominator:

```
solution1 = (-b + ((b**2 - 4 * a * c)**0.5)) / (2 * a)
```

Comment: Thanks, I never even thought of that!